# Exclude last data or row from the fatched data - SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

```
    SELECT * FROM time_slot JOIN reseve_slot ON reserv_start_time WHERE reserv_date = '09-07-2015' AND (time_slot NOT BETWEEN reserv_start_time AND reserv_end_time)
```

Comment: use `NOT IN` with sub query and order by and `limit 1`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to go on what you asked but it seems you want the query results as they are minus the very last returned row.

Here's a verbose example to show the removal clearly:

```
$query = "select * from time_slot join reseve_slot on reserv_start_time where reserv_date = '09-07-2015' and (time_slot NOT between reserv_start_time and reserv_end_time)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die($mysqli->error);
$resultArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if (!is_null($resultArray)) {
    //remove the last result
    $wantedResult = array_pop($resultArray);

    // now do something with the returned results $wantedResult
}
```